# Random walk problem in the plane

Tags: probability, geometry, random-walk

Let a particle in the plane $R^2$ executes random jumps at discrete times $t= 1, 2, ...$. At each step, the particle jumps from the point it is a distance of lenght one. The angle of any new jump (say, with the $x$ axis) is uniformly distributed in $[0,2\pi]$.

Question: If initially ($t=0$) the particle is at the origin, what is the probability that it gets back to the unit disk of the plane for each time $t= 2, 3, 4, ...$? In particular, what is the value of this probability for $t=3$?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
The probability density for the step $n$ is given by
$\ds{{\rm p}\pars{\vec{r}_{n}} \equiv {\delta\pars{r_{n} - 1} \over 2\pi}}$. The probability density $\pp_{N}\pars{\vec{r}}$ of arriving at $\vec{r}$ after $N$ steps is given by:

> \begin{align}
> \pp_{N}\pars{\vec{r}}
> &\equiv
> \int\dd^{2}\vec{r}_{1}\,{\rm p}\pars{\vec{r}_{1}}\ldots
> \int\dd^{2}\vec{r}_{N}{\rm p}\pars{\vec{r}_{N}}
> \delta\pars{\vec{r} - \sum_{\ell = 1}^{N}\vec{r}_{\ell}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \int\dd^{2}\vec{r}_{1}\,{\rm p}\pars{\vec{r}_{1}}\ldots
> \int\dd^{2}\vec{r}_{N}{\rm p}\pars{\vec{r}_{N}}
> \int\exp\pars{\ic\vec{k}\cdot\bracks{\vec{r} - \sum_{\ell = 1}^{N}\vec{r}_{\ell}}}
> \,{\dd^{2}\vec{k} \over \pars{2\pi}^{2}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \int\expo{\ic\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}
> \bracks{\int\dd^{2}\vec{R}\,{\rm p}\pars{\vec{R}}\expo{-\ic\vec{k}\cdot\vec{R}}}^{N}
> \,{\dd^{2}\vec{k} \over \pars{2\pi}^{2}}
> =
> \int\expo{\ic\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}
> \bracks{\int_{0}^{2\pi}\expo{-\ic k\cos\pars{\theta}}\,{\dd\theta \over 2\pi}}^{N}
> \,{\dd^{2}\vec{k} \over \pars{2\pi}^{2}}
> \end{align}

However
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\expo{-\ic k\cos\pars{\theta}}\,{\dd\theta \over 2\pi}
=
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\expo{\ic k\cos\pars{\theta}}\,{\dd\theta \over 2\pi}
=
{1 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\expo{\ic k\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
=
{\rm J}_{0}\pars{k}
$$
where ${\rm J}_{\nu}\pars{k}$ is the
$\nu$-$\it\mbox{order Bessel Function of the First Kind}$.

> \begin{align}
> \pp_{N}\pars{\vec{r}}
> &=
> \int\expo{\ic\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}{\rm J}_{0}^{N}\pars{k}
> \,{\dd^{2}\vec{k} \over \pars{2\pi}^{2}}
> =
> {1 \over 2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd k\,k\,{\rm J}_{0}^{N}\pars{k}\int_{0}^{2\pi}
> \expo{\ic kr\cos\pars{\theta}}\,{\dd\theta \over 2\pi}
> \end{align}
> $$
> \color{#ff0000}{\pp_{N}\pars{\vec{r}}
> =
> {1 \over 2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm J}_{0}\pars{kr}{\rm J}_{0}^{N}\pars{k}k
> \,\dd k}
> $$

The probability ${\rm P}_{N{\Huge\circ}}$ that it returns to the unit circle after $N$ steps is given by:
\begin{align}
\color{#0000ff}{\large{\rm P}_{N{\Huge\circ}}}
&=
\int_{r\ <\ 1}\pp_{N}\pars{\vec{r}}\,\dd^{2}\vec{r}
=
\int_{0}^{\infty}\overbrace{\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}{\rm J}_{0}\pars{kr}r\,\dd r}}
^{{\rm J}_{1}\pars{k}/k}
{\rm J}_{0}^{N}\pars{k}k\,\dd k
\\[3mm]&=
\color{#0000ff}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm J}_{1}\pars{k}
{\rm J}_{0}^{N}\pars{k}\,\dd k}
\end{align}
We compute a few values with Wolfram Alpha:
$$
\begin{array}{rclrcl}
{\rm P}_{0{\Huge\circ}} =\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm J}_{1}\pars{k}
\,\dd k & = & 1\,,\quad
{\rm P}_{1{\Huge\circ}} =\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm J}_{1}\pars{k}
{\rm J}_{0}\pars{k}\,\dd k & = & \half
\\
{\rm P}_{2{\Huge\circ}} =\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm J}_{1}\pars{k}{\rm J}_{0}^{2}\pars{k}
\,\dd k & = & {1 \over 3}\,,\quad
{\rm P}_{3{\Huge\circ}} =\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm J}_{1}\pars{k}
{\rm J}_{0}^{3}\pars{k}\,\dd k & = & {1 \over 4}
\\
{\rm P}_{4{\Huge\circ}} =\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm J}_{1}\pars{k}{\rm J}_{0}^{4}\pars{k}
\,\dd k & = & {1 \over 5}\,,\quad
{\rm P}_{5{\Huge\circ}} =\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm J}_{1}\pars{k}
{\rm J}_{0}^{5}\pars{k}\,\dd k & = & {1 \over 6}
\end{array}
$$

It $\tt\large seems$ the exact result is
$\ds{%
{\rm P}_{N{\Huge\circ}}
=
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm J}_{1}\pars{k}{\rm J}_{0}^{N}\pars{k} \,\dd k
=
{1 \over N + 1}}$

Mathematica can solve this integral and it yields the $\ul{\mbox{exact result}}$ $\color{#0000ff}{\Large{1 \over N + 1}}$ when $\color{#ff0000}{\large\Re N > -1}$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic problem, first solved by the Dutch mathematician J.C. Kluyver in 1905. He derives the result given in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/612395/87355) of Felix Marin, that the probability to return to the unit disc after $n$ steps is $1/(n+1)$:

[image]

[image]

For a purely geometric derivation, see [arXiv:1007.4870](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.4870). (There the result is attributed to Rayleigh, but it appears Rayleigh only considered the large-$n$ limit.) See also this [MO posting.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/347336/11260)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a probility dristribution for the location after one step (the unit circle with a certain constant prbability). After two steps, I think that should be doable too. You can also carculate for each point the probability of entering de unit disk in the next step. Then, by combining the probability distribution ($P_1(x,y)$) and the probability of ending in the disk $P_2(x,y)$, you get
$$
\int P_1(x,y)P_2(x,y) \,dx\,dy
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but is kind of long for a comment.

For $t=2$, draw a picture.  It's pretty easy to see the answer is $1/3$.

For the $t=3$ case, let the angles be $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, and $\theta_3$.  By symmetry, you can assume without loss of generality that $\theta_1 = 0$.  So you need to find the probability that
$\|\langle 1, 0 \rangle +  \langle \cos\theta_2, \sin\theta_2 \rangle  +\langle \cos\theta_3,\sin\theta_3\rangle \|<1$.  A little computation shows that this is equals 
$P(1+\cos\theta_2+\cos\theta_3+\cos(\theta_2-\theta_3)<0)$, where $\theta_2$ and $\theta_3$ are chosen independently from the uniform distribution on $[0,2\pi]$.  That's as far as I got.

This is the probability that the particle is in the unit disc *at time* $t=3$ (not $t$ equals 2 or 3).

Answer (score 0):

This addresses the t=3 case:

Assume you start at origin ($P_0$), and without loss of generality, assume first move is to $P_1=(1, 0)$. Your second move will be to $P_2=(1 + cos(\theta),  sin(\theta))$, where theta is uniform [0, $\pi$] (can ignore the [$\pi,2\pi$] range due to symmetry). Density function of $\theta$ is just $f(\theta)=\frac{1}{\pi}$

Draw unit-circles around $P_0$ and $P_2$, and let X be the second intersection point of these two circles (aside from $P_1$).

Now draw the quadrilateral  $\overline{P_0P_1P_2X}$. Turns out this is actually a rhombus, with each side of length 1. From geometry of parallel-lines, one can see that the angle $\angle P_1P_2X$ equals theta. Also, this angle $\theta$ subtends the arc of the $P_2$ circle that is inside the $P_0$ circle.

Therefore, for any given $\theta$, the probability that a chosen point on the $P_2$ circle will be inside the $P_0$ circle is simply $\frac{\theta}{2\pi}$.

Putting this all together, the probability that we return to the unit-circle after 3 moves is:
$\int^\pi_0(1/\pi) * (\theta/2\pi) d\theta = 1/4$